# VM instance with OS-Login not working or unable to ssh into compute VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, roles, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

i have enabled os login feature into one of the proxy vm instance.
But am not able to SSH because i had to add my public key into the compute as follows,

```
gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys add --key-file=~/.ssh/google_compute.pub --ttl=365d
```

It says,

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.os-login.ssh-keys.add) User [user@gmail.com] does not have permission to access users instance [suser@gmail.com:importSshPublicKey] (or it may not exist): Insufficient IAM permissions. The instance belongs to an external organization. You must be granted the roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser IAM role on the external organization to configure POSIX account information.
```

so i checked further and all my projects does not have organization it says No Organization so i go with below command to add osLoginExternalUser permission but,

```
gcloud beta compute instances add-iam-policy-binding vm-instance-name --zone=us-central1-a --member='user:user@gmail.com' --role='roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser'
```

but this results in below error,

```
ERROR: Policy modification failed. For a binding with condition, run "gcloud alpha iam policies lint-condition" to identify issues in condition.
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.instances.add-iam-policy-binding) HTTPError 400: Role roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser is not supported for this resource.
```

what's going on!!! Please help.

+Adding project info using command

```
gcloud compute project-info describe

commonInstanceMetadata:
  fingerprint: NzXW3s3apL4=
  items:
  - key: ssh-keys
    value: |
      user:ssh-rsa ... google-ssh {"userName":"user@gmail.com","expireOn":"2021-03-04T10:55:54+0000"}
      user:ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 ...= google-ssh {"userName":"user@gmail.com","expireOn":"2021-03-04T10:55:53+0000"}
      user:ssh-rsa ... user@cs-1234-default-default-8fz65
      user:ssh-rsa .. A\user@PCNAME
  - key: sshKeys
    value: |2-
        ....
  kind: compute#metadata
defaultNetworkTier: PREMIUM
defaultServiceAccount: user-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
id: '1234'
kind: compute#project
name: project-name
quotas:
- limit: 25000.0
  metric: SNAPSHOTS
    usage: 0.0
- limit: 50.0
  metric: NETWORKS
  usage: 9.0
- limit: 500.0
  metric: FIREWALLS
  usage: 12.0
- limit: 10000.0
  metric: IMAGES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 700.0
  metric: STATIC_ADDRESSES
  usage: 1.0
- limit: 500.0
  metric: ROUTES
  usage: 10.0
- limit: 375.0
  metric: FORWARDING_RULES
  usage: 2.0
- limit: 1250.0
  metric: TARGET_POOLS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 1250.0
  metric: HEALTH_CHECKS
  usage: 4.0
- limit: 2300.0
  metric: IN_USE_ADDRESSES
  usage: 2.0
- limit: 1250.0
  metric: TARGET_INSTANCES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 250.0
  metric: TARGET_HTTP_PROXIES
  usage: 2.0
- limit: 250.0
  metric: URL_MAPS
  usage: 2.0
- limit: 75.0
  metric: BACKEND_SERVICES
  usage: 4.0
- limit: 2500.0
 metric: INSTANCE_TEMPLATES
  usage: 6.0
- limit: 125.0
  metric: TARGET_VPN_GATEWAYS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 250.0
  metric: VPN_TUNNELS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 75.0
  metric: BACKEND_BUCKETS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 20.0
  metric: ROUTERS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 250.0
  metric: TARGET_SSL_PROXIES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 250.0
  metric: TARGET_HTTPS_PROXIES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 250.0
  metric: SSL_CERTIFICATES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 275.0
  metric: SUBNETWORKS
  usage: 174.0
- limit: 250.0
  metric: TARGET_TCP_PROXIES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 10.0
  metric: SECURITY_POLICIES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 200.0
  metric: SECURITY_POLICY_RULES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 1000.0
  metric: XPN_SERVICE_PROJECTS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 375.0
  metric: PACKET_MIRRORINGS
  usage: 0.0
  - limit: 2500.0
  metric: NETWORK_ENDPOINT_GROUPS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 6.0
  metric: INTERCONNECTS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 5000.0
  metric: GLOBAL_INTERNAL_ADDRESSES
  usage: 11.0
- limit: 125.0
  metric: VPN_GATEWAYS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 10000.0
  metric: MACHINE_IMAGES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 20.0
  metric: SECURITY_POLICY_CEVAL_RULES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 125.0
  metric: EXTERNAL_VPN_GATEWAYS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 1.0
  metric: PUBLIC_ADVERTISED_PREFIXES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 10.0
  metric: PUBLIC_DELEGATED_PREFIXES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 1024.0
  metric: STATIC_BYOIP_ADDRESSES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 375.0
  metric: INTERNAL_TRAFFIC_DIRECTOR_FORWARDING_RULES
  usage: 0.0
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project-name
xpnProjectStatus: UNSPECIFIED_XPN_PROJECT_STATUS
user@cs-154457833976-default-default-gl5qv:~$ commonInstanceMetadata:
-bash: commonInstanceMetadata:: command not found
user@cs-154457833976-default-default-gl5qv:~$   fingerprint: NzXW3s3apL4=
-bash: fingerprint:: command not found
user@cs-154457833976-default-default-gl5qv:~$   items:
-bash: items:: command not found
user@cs-154457833976-default-default-gl5qv:~$   fingerprint: NzXW3s3apL4=
-bash: fingerprint:: command not found
user@cs-154457833976-default-default-gl5qv:~$   items:
-bash: items:: command not found
user@cs-154457833976-default-default-gl5qv:~$   - key: ssh-keys
-bash: -: command not found
user@cs-154457833976-default-default-gl5qv:~$     value: |
>       user:ssh-rsa ...= google-ssh {"userName":"user@gmail.com","expireOn":"2021-03-04T10:55:54+0000"}
-bash: value:: command not found
-bash: user:ssh-rsa: command not found
user@cs-154457833976-default-default-gl5qv:~$       user:ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 ...= google-ssh {"userName":"user@gmail.com","expireOn":"2021-03-04T10:55:53+0000"}
-bash: user:ecdsa-sha2-nistp256: command not found
user@cs-154457833976-default-default-gl5qv:~$       user:ssh-rsa ... user@cs-154457833976-default-default-8fz65
-bash: user:ssh-rsa: command not found
user@cs-154457833976-default-default-gl5qv:~$       user:ssh-rsa ... A\user@PCNAME
-bash: user:ssh-rsa: command not found
user@cs-154457833976-default-default-gl5qv:~$   - key: sshKeys
-bash: -: command not found
```

+Adding more project IAM permissions:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy test-project

bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:sql-instance-proxy@test-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/cloudsql.editor
- members:
  - user:user@gmail.com
  role: roles/compute.osAdminLogin
- members:
  - user:user@gmail.com
  role: roles/owner
etag: BwW8ubx4adY=
version: 1
```

Comment: 1) The role `roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser` is not supported for Compute Engine resources, only at the Organization level. 2) Instead grant the role `roles/compute.osLogin` to the Compute Engine resource. 3) For this error `The instance belongs to an external organization.` I will need more information on the project and the user identity. Edit your question with details.

Comment: @John Hanley Thanks for clarification. The user does have owner and compute.osadminlogin permissions. And the project has No Organization. Will add more info on project by running gcloud compute project-info describe command in question asap.

Comment: @JohnHanley have added more info in the original question.. let me know if that helps or should i need to run any specific commands..

Answer (score 2):

I’ve seen this error before.
If you don't belong to the same organization where your project is located you won’t be able to see the organization. I mean, you may have the owner role in your project, but if you don’t belong to the organization you can’t see the organization name under [Manage resources](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager) and you only will be able to see the project under the `No Organization` section.

[image]

According to the documentation: [Configuring OS Login roles on user accounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#configure_users)

> For users that are outside of your organization to access your VMs, in addition to granting an instance access role, grant the roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser role. This role must be granted at the organization level by an **organization administrator**.

The [roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.osLoginExternalUser) IAM role lets external Google Accounts interact with the other OS Login roles by allowing them to configure POSIX account information, but as @John mentioned this role is only available at the organization level, that is why an organization administrator should granted this role.
Please check the following documentation for further information: [Granting instance access to users outside of your organization](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/manage-oslogin-in-an-org#external-user)

In summary, you need to contact the organization administrator to grant the `roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser` role.